# C# Winforms ID barcode reader using ZXing.Net

Tags: c#, winforms, reader, zxing.net

Iam trying to make IDs reader using C# Winforms application with ZXing.net library.

I found a simple example like this one but it didn't works well
both results are always null

Iam trying to figure out what is the proplem !!!

```
IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
reader.Options.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
reader.Options.PossibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.PDF_417);
reader.Options.PossibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.RSS_14);
reader.Options.TryHarder = true;

var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("d:\\5.png");
var res1 = reader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
var res2 = reader.DecodeMultiple(barcodeBitmap);
```

any help !

Comment: If you don't know what is the problem, how could we possibly help you? What happens when you run this code?

Comment: This makes me chuckle: `reader.Options.TryHarder = true;`

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto .. did you mean it really?? i wrote the results are always null, no exception thrown

Comment: @LarsTech this is real property in this sdk bro, try it 

Comment: @LarsTech, IKR, obviously the developer struggled to find a name for this property!

Answer (score 0):

When the result is null, it means that the image couldn't be decoded to any of the `PossibleFormats`. If you're not sure about the format of the barcode/QR code, you can simply remove all the expected format in order to let it accept any format:

```
IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();

using (var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"d:\5.png"))
{
    var result = reader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
    if (result != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.Text);
        // You can also use the following to determine the Barcode format.
        Console.WriteLine(result.BarcodeFormat.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: well thanks to your suggestion. but it still the same

Comment: Read the first line of my answer. Furthermore, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50996695/edit) your question and include the barcode image you're using if you think it should be able to decode it.